# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open COM3

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, arduino, serial-port

hey i'm trying to program my arduino to connect to node js but there's a problem with the COM3 port can anyone help?

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = require("@serialport/parser-readline");

const port = new SerialPort("COM3",{
baudRate:9600,
});
const parser = new Readline();
port.pipe(parser);
parser.on('data', (line) => console.log(line));
port.write("ngentod")
```

Comment: `COM3` is the device name on your Windows PC. Does the program you presented work on a Windows PC? Or does it work with Arduino? [Arduino and Node.js via Serial port](https://medium.com/@machadogj/arduino-and-node-js-via-serial-port-bcf9691fab6a), [Node Js communication with Arduino via serialport](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/31580/node-js-communication-with-arduino-via-serialport)

Answer (score 0):

On your Windows PC, open the Arduino IDE and find the Arduino board. Check to make sure it is actually on COM3 and that the baud rate is 9600. Outside of that, your code looks fine. If you run into any more errors I'd recommend being slightly more specific with what is going wrong, so I can give you more well-tailored advice that can help fix your problem faster.